# unable to write query with string not equals in realm swift

Tags: swift, realm

I am changing my SQLite database into a realm, but I am unable to convert the SQLite query to the realm

I have tried with `!=` and `NOT CONTAINS` but it didn't work. how to achieve this?

below is my old SQLite query, I am trying to convert this to realm DB

```
select COUNT(*) from (tabledata)
where  ifnull(length((KEY_DATA)), 0) <> 0 and
       lower((KEY_DATA)) <> lower('N/A') and
       lower((KEY_DATA)) <> lower('NA') and
       lower((KEY_DATA)) <> lower('not applicable')
```

i am trying like

```
let countpredicate = NSPredicate(format: "data.length > 0 AND data != [c]'N/A' AND data != [c]'NA' AND data != [c]'not applicable'")
```

what is wrong in this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should combine `[c]` with the operand not the string

```
let countpredicate = NSPredicate(format: "data.length > 0 AND data !=[c] 'N/A' AND data !=[c] 'NA' AND data !=[c] 'not applicable'")
```

Maybe you can use IN

```
let countpredicate = NSPredicate(format: "data.length > 0 AND data NOT IN[c] ('N/A','NA','not applicable'")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your predicate has not constructed properly:

Replace

> (***data** not empty*)
>
> `data.length > 0` to `data != ''`

and

> (***data** not contains*)
>
> `data != [c]'<insert text>'` to `!(data contains[c] '<insert text>')`

Final:

```
NSPredicate(format: "data != %@ && !(data contains[c] %@) && !(data contains[c] %@) && !(data contains[c] %@)", "", "N/A", "NA", "not applicable")
```

Comment: Thanks for Answer i have tried it , app getting crashed
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "data !=  && !(data contains[c] N/A) && !(data contains[c] NA) && !(data contains[c] not applicable )"'

Comment: Your **data !=** has no value set

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
let countpredicate = NSPredicate(format: "data.length > 0 AND data !CONTAINS[c] 'N/A' AND data !CONTAINS[c] 'NA' AND data !CONTAINS[c] 'not applicable'")
```

`[c]` means case incensitive